# Ordenar prioridad al hacer un update

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

Tengo la siguiente tabla donde la ordeno por prioridad `ASC`

```
 ----------------------
|prioridad|actividad  |
|---------|-----------|
|   1     |act1       |
|   2     |act2       |
|   3     |act3       |
|   4     |act4       |
|   5     |act5       |
|---------|-----------|
```

Tengo en JSON donde realizo un update

**Agrego Método pero no funciona como yo deseo**

```
 <?php
    //update.php
    include_once('../include/conexion.php');

    $query = "
     UPDATE ACT_Agenda SET ".$_POST["name"]." = '".$_POST["value"]."'
     WHERE id_agenda = '".$_POST["pk"]."'";

//method for order priority

    $resultt=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if ($resultt) {
        $query2 = "UPDATE ACT_Agenda SET prioridad = CASE 
               WHEN prioridad >= " . $_POST['value'] . "
               THEN prioridad + 1 ELSE prioridad  END
               WHERE id_agenda <> '" . $_POST['pk'] . "'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
        echo "YES";
    }  ?>
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que me Ordena la prioridad, es decir si yo actualizo la `act5` que tiene prioridad 5 a prioridad 1, la prioridad cambia y eso quiere decir que la prioridad de la `act1` debe cambiar a 2 y así sucesivamente hasta que la `act4` quede con prioridad 5.

Con ese Codigo aportado por `@Sr1871` Funciona bien si actualizo la ultima prioridad. Pero si actualizo la `act4` a prioridad 1 las de abajo no deberían actualizarse pero lo hacen sumando +1( `act5` prioridad 5 queda 6 ).

Algo así me gustaría si actualizo `act4` a prioridad 1

```
     ----------------------
    |prioridad|actividad  |
    |---------|-----------|
    |   1     |act4       |
    |   2     |act1       |
    |   3     |act2       |
    |   4     |act3       |
    |   5     |act5       |
    |---------|-----------|
```

Espero haberme explicado bien. Saludos.

Mi Formulario

```
    <td data-name="prioridad" class="prioridad"  data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $row['id_agenda'] ?>">
        <?php echo $row['prioridad']; ?>
   </td>


   $('#employee_data').editable({
            container: 'body',
            selector: 'td.prioridad',
            url: "JSON/updateCorelativoJSON.php",
            // url: "update.php",
            title: 'Editar Prioridad',
            type: "POST",
            //dataType: 'json',
            validate: function(value) {
                if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                    return 'Este campo es necesario';
                }
            },
            success: function(data) {
              if (data == "YES") {
                          location.reload();
                      } else {
                          alert("ERROR");
                          location.reload();
                      }
            }
        });
```

Comment: ¿pero hay algo que no funciona? ¿genera un error? Te recomiendo hacer la prueba tu mismo y en base a eso nos cuentas.

Comment: Funciona bien, deseo saber como puedo `reordenar` los valores en la base de datos ejemplo si la `act3` tiene prioridad  3 y la actualizo a 1 se me debe reordenar mi tabla `act3`- 1 | `act1`- 2 | `act2` -3

Comment: ¿te refieres a que después de hacer el _update_ el orden de guardado va a variar? o ¿si después del _update_ el _select_ con el _order by_ mostrará en orden `ASC`?

Comment: @ValVert Después de hacer un update el orden varia en la tabla

Comment: No, según recuerdo, el orden de almacenamiento no varía.

Comment: Mi campo `prioridad` no es UNIQUE ni PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Aunque no lo sea, el orden de guardado no lo puedes varias a menos que elimines las filas y las vuelvas a insertar nuevamente.

Comment: La consulta no era la adecuada, en unos momentos que tenga más tiempo vuelvo a tratar de hacerla

Comment: @Sr1871 Muchas gracias mirare algunos ejemplos. Agradecido!

Comment: @Sr1871 Encontré este método pero igual no funciona https://www.webslesson.info/2017/06/sorting-table-row-using-jquery-drag-drop-with-ajax-php.html?m=1

Comment: Quizas ahi el concepto de prioridad si esta solo ligado a la fecha de creación, yo añadiría una columna fecha de creación y la ordenaría de ese modo, el id de prioridad podría estar del lado de la aplicación.

Comment: @JoelIbaceta Lo que deseo es al poder cambiar la prioridad recorra todas y las cambie ejemplo `act2` tiene prioridad 2 si la cambio a prioridad 1 la `act1` teniendo prioridad 1 cambia a 2 y la `act3` no cambia su prioridad porque no es menor que la prioridad que se cambia. Despues para el orden en la vista realizo un  `ORDEN BY prioridad ASC`

Comment: El problema de la ordenación es que debes tener en cuenta tanto el nuevo orden del registro modificado como el anterior, para no tocar aquellos registros que se queden fuera del rango afectado

Comment: @JaviMollá algo asi?  `WHEN prioridad >= ".$_POST['value']."  OR prioridad =< ".$_POST['value']."`

Comment: el campo prioridad es único? es decir puede existir momentáneamente dos prioridad uno? te pregunto porque si no es único creo que tengo la solución

Comment: tendrás que guardarte el orden original antes del primer update y usarlo de modo: prioridad >= nuevoOrden and prioridad < anteriorOrden. luego intento escribirlo todo en una respuesta

Comment: como estás editando la prioridad? podrías subir una imagen de como la editas actualmente? es decir el formulario

Comment: @Sr1871 Listo agregue mi formulario

Comment: Me parece interesante [lo que comenta @JoelIbaceta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194267/ordenar-prioridad-al-hacer-un-update#comment365518_194267). ¿No se resuelve tu problema mediante una columna del tipo `TIMESTAMP` indicando al manejador que esa columna tome por defecto el momento actual al crearse y que se actualice al momento actual si la fila es actualizada? Hacerlo de otro modo me parece bastante complejo y difícil de mantener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambiar la prioridad de un registro, se puede pensar como la sucesión de los siguientes eventos:

1. **"Sacamos el registro"**: por lo que, todos aquellos registros cuya prioridad sean mayor deben decrementarse en 1, es decir:

   ```
   UPDATE ACT_Agenda
     SET prioridad = prioridad - 1 
     WHERE prioridad > ?
   ```
2. **"Agregamos el registro"**: por lo que, todos aquellos registros cuya prioridad sea mayor o igual debe incrementarse en 1, es decir:

   ```
   UPDATE ACT_Agenda
     SET prioridad = prioridad + 1 
     WHERE prioridad >= ?
   ```

## Solución:

Por [razones de seguridad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/16597) sería optimo que usaras [sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), por lo que el código podría ser el siguiente:

```
<?php
//update.php
include_once('../include/conexion.php');

// Validamos que el registro existe y 
// obtenemos la prioridad que tiene
$query = "SELECT prioridad 
    FROM ACT_Agenda 
    WHERE id_agenda = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_POST["pk"]);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $prioridadAnt);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    // Si se modifico la prioridad
    if ($prioridadAnt != $_POST['value']) {

        // Actualizamos todos los registros cuya prioridad
        // sea mayor a la prioridad anterior (1)
        $query = "UPDATE ACT_Agenda
          SET prioridad = prioridad - 1 
          WHERE prioridad > $prioridadAnt";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        // Actualizamos todos los registros cuya prioridad
        // sea mayor igual a la nueva prioridad (2)
        $query = "UPDATE ACT_Agenda
          SET prioridad = prioridad + 1 
          WHERE prioridad >= ?";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_POST["value"]);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }

    // Actualizamos la prioridad
    $query = "UPDATE ACT_Agenda 
        SET prioridad = ?
        WHERE id_agenda = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $_POST["value"], $_POST["pk"]);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta... una consulta PDO sirve con PHP 5.6 ?

Comment: @MoteCL, si podrias usar tranquilamente PDO en lugar de MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

Es necesario traer el valor previo para poder hacerlo correctamente.

Si la extensión que estás usando es x-editable, puedes hacerlo de esta forma
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885286/x-editable-submit-old-value

Si no tienes forma de traerlo o quieres hacerlo más seguro desde el backend, puedes traerlo con un `SELECT` antes de hacer el `UPDATE`

```
//Aquí iría el select

$query = "
 UPDATE ACT_Agenda SET ".$_POST["name"]." = '".$_POST["value"]."'
 WHERE id_agenda = '".$_POST["pk"]."'";
```

Si el valor nuevo es menor al anterior, tienes que sumarle uno a todos los que sean mayores o iguales hasta el número anterior, si por el contrario el valor nuevo es menor al nuevo tienes que restarle 1 a todos los que sean menores hasta el número anterior

Básicamente

```
A = valor nuevo
B = valor anterior
V = valor de otro registro

Si A < B
   Suma 1 si V >= A && V < B;

Si A > B
   Resta 1 si V < A && V >= B
```

Ejemplo

```
-----------------------
|prioridad|actividad  |
|---------|-----------|
|   1     |act4       |
|   2     |act1       |
|   3     |act2       |
|   2     |act3       | //act3 paso a prioridad 2, la anterior era 4
|   5     |act5       |
|---------|-----------|
```

Entonces como mencioné, el valor nuevo es menor al anterior, entonces hay que sumarle 1 a todos los valores mayores e iguales que 2 y menores que 4

En este caso solo se le sumaría a la prioridad 2 convirtiéndola en 3 y la prioridad 3 convirtiéndola en 4

EJEMPLO CASO CONTRARIO

```
 -----------------------
|prioridad|actividad  |
|---------|-----------|
|   1     |act4       |
|   4     |act1       | //act1 paso a prioridad 4, la anterior 2
|   3     |act2       |
|   4     |act3       |
|   5     |act5       |
|---------|-----------|
```

Como ahora el número nuevo es mayor al anterior le restamos a todos los números que sean mayores a 2 y menores o igual a 4;
en este caso solo se le restaría a 3, convirtiéndolo en 2 y a 4 convirtiéndolo en 3

En tu base de datos actualiza directamente en la consulta desde el php,

```
<?php
//update.php
include_once('../include/conexion.php');

$query = "
 UPDATE ACT_Agenda SET ".$_POST["name"]." = '".$_POST["value"]."'
 WHERE id_agenda = '".$_POST["pk"]."'";
$resultt=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if($resultt && $_POST["name"] == 'prioridad'){
   if($valorAnterior < $_POST["value"])
       $query2 = "UPDATE ACT_Agenda SET prioridad = prioridad + 1
     WHERE id_agenda <> $_POST['pk'] AND prioridad BETWEEN $valorAnterior AND $_POST['value']";
   else
       $query2 = "UPDATE ACT_Agenda SET prioridad = prioridad - 1
     WHERE id_agenda <> $_POST['pk'] AND prioridad BETWEEN $valorAnterior AND $_POST['value']";


   mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
}
if($resultt) {
  echo "YES";
 } else {
  echo "NO";
}
?>
```

Donde **$valorAnterior** es el valor anterior que mencionaba al principio, ya sea que te lo puedas traer desde el `POST` en el formulario o desde la consulta SQL, queda a tu elección.

**NOTA**: esto lo hice con sql directo dado que así está tu consulta para que le entendieras, pero esta forma no es nada recomendable, deberías buscar y leer sobre consultas preparadas, ya que es la forma adecuada de hacer consultas sql

Comment: No se necesita alterar el orden de las prioridades que son menores a la que se cambio.

Comment: Es necesario, dado que si la prioridad 1 la cambia a prioridad 6, la prioridad 6 tiene que pasar a prioridad 5, la 5 a 4 ..., si cambia la prioridad 1 a prioridad 3, la prioridad 3 tiene que pasar a prioridad 4, la 4 a 5, y la prioridad  2, la 2 a 1 ...

Comment: Modifique la respuesta, para que la revises

Answer (score 0):

Hola esto te funcionaria, te he agregado una clase para la conexion a la base datos, me imagino que tendras la tuya, pero como lo he hecho utilizando este archivo que lo tenia ya hecho, te la he puesto, por si no entiendes algo.

```
<?php
        $activityToUpdate = 5;
        $id_agenda;
        $row = 2;
        $servidor = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $password = "******";
        $baseDatos = "AGENDA";
        require_once '../conexionMysqli.php';
        $agenda = new ServidorBaseDatos($servidor, $user, $password, $baseDatos);
        $agenda->consulta("SELECT * FROM act_agenda WHERE ID_AGENDA !=".$activityToUpdate." ORDER BY PRIORIDAD ASC");
        $update = new ServidorBaseDatos($servidor, $user, $password, $baseDatos);
        echo '<p>ACTIVIDAD: '.$activityToUpdate." PRIORIDAD: 1</p>";
        while ($fila = $agenda->extraerRegistro()) {
                    foreach ($fila as $indice => $valor) {
                        switch ($indice){
                            case 'ID_AGENDA':
                                $id_agenda = $valor;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    $update->consulta("UPDATE act_agenda SET PRIORIDAD=".$row." WHERE ID_AGENDA=".$id_agenda);
                    echo '<p>ID_AGENDA: '.$id_agenda." PRIORIDAD: ".$row."</p>";
                    $row += 1; 
                }
                $update->consulta("UPDATE act_agenda SET PRIORIDAD=1 WHERE ID_AGENDA=".$activityToUpdate);
                $update->cerrarConexion();
                $agenda->cerrarConexion();
        ?>
```

Esta seria otra manera de hacerlo:

```
   <?php
    $activityToUpdate = 10;
    $row = 1;
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "*******";
    $baseDatos = "AGENDA";
    require_once '../conexionMysqli.php';
    $agenda = new ServidorBaseDatos($servidor, $user, $password, $baseDatos);
    $agenda->consulta("SELECT * FROM act_agenda ORDER BY PRIORIDAD ASC");
    $id_agenda;
    $prioridad;
    $actividad;
    while ($fila = $agenda->extraerRegistro()) {
                $update = new ServidorBaseDatos($servidor, $user, $password, $baseDatos);
                foreach ($fila as $indice => $valor) {
                    switch ($indice){
                        case 'ID_AGENDA':
                            $id_agenda = $valor;
                            break;
                        case 'PRIORIDAD':
                            $prioridad = $valor;
                            break;
                        case 'ACTIVIDAD':
                            $actividad = $valor;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if($id_agenda==$activityToUpdate && $prioridad==1){
                    $row =0;
                } else if($id_agenda==$activityToUpdate && $row>0) {
                    $prioridad = 1;
                    $update->consulta("UPDATE act_agenda SET PRIORIDAD=".$prioridad." WHERE ID_AGENDA=".$activityToUpdate);
                } else if($prioridad<=$row && $row>0){
                    $row = $row + 1;
                    $update->consulta("UPDATE act_agenda SET PRIORIDAD=".$row." WHERE ID_AGENDA=".$id_agenda);   
                }
                echo '<p>INDICE: '.$id_agenda." PRIORIDAD: ".$prioridad." ACTIVIDAD: ".$actividad."</p>";
                $update->cerrarConexion();
            }
            $agenda->cerrarConexion();
    ?>
```

Esta es la clase que he utilizado para la conexion de la base datos:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

class ServidorBaseDatos {

    private $servidor;
    private $usuario;
    private $password;
    private $baseDatos;
    private $descriptor;

    function __construct($servidor, $user, $password, $baseDatos) {
        $this->servidor = $servidor;
        $this->usuario = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->baseDatos = $baseDatos;
        $this->conectarBaseDatos();
    }

    private function conectarBaseDatos() {
        $this->descriptor = mysqli_connect($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->password, $this->baseDatos);
    }

    public function consulta($consulta) {
        $this->resultado = mysqli_query($this->descriptor, $consulta);
    }

    public function extraerRegistro() {
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($this->resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if ($fila) {
            return $fila;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function cerrarConexion() {
        mysqli_close($this->descriptor);
    }

}
```

Tambien podrias hacer una funcion dentro de la clase ServidorBaseDatos, asi poder acceder a la funcion desde cualquier parte de la aplicacion.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente update:

```
$consulta = '
update ACT_AGENDA
set prioridad = case 
  when prioridad < (select prioridad 
                    from (SELECT * FROM ACT_AGENDA) as t 
                    where id_agenda = '.$_POST['pk'].') 
       and prioridad >= '.$_POST['value'].'
    then prioridad + 1
  when prioridad > (select prioridad 
                    from (SELECT * FROM ACT_AGENDA) as t 
                    where id_agenda = '.$_POST['pk'].') 
       and prioridad <= '.$_POST['value'].'
     then prioridad - 1
  when id_agenda = '.$_POST['pk'].' then '.$_POST['value'].'
  else prioridad
end
';
```

[**En este enlace**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6i1L1kJSKtMXaEGegYap1U/2) tienes un ejemplo de ese mismo update. En el ejemplo, cambio la categoría 5: del valor original 5 al nuevo valor 2

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que `UPDATE`ar toda la tabla con los nuevos valores ordenados, una forma de lograrlo es con un query que retorne las prioridades cambiadas dejando espacio entre las prioridades para meter ahí la nueva prioridad.

### A. la consulta SELECT

Para lograrlo primero hacemos un `SELECT` que retorne la `prioridad original * 2`, así hay espacio para meter el elemento que cambia.
Caso especial es la actividad que cambia de prioridad, para esta se retorna `nueva prioridad * 2 - 1` si la prioridad nueva es menor y `nueva prioridad * 2 + 1` si es mayor o igual (a la prioridad actual). Esta diferencia es para que caiga antes o después de la actividad que "reemplaza".

un ejemplo para verlo mas claro:

Cambiar `act5` a prioridad `3` :

```
-------------------------------
|prioridad|actividad|prioridad|
|original |         |temporal |
|---------|---------|---------|
|   1     |act1     |    2    |  <- original(1) * 2 -> 1*2 = 2
|   2     |act2     |    4    |
|   3     |act3     |    6    |  <- original(3) * 2 -> 3*2 = 6
|   4     |act4     |    8    |
|   5     |act5     |    5    |  <- original(5) >= nueva(3) -> nueva * 2 - 1 -> 3*2-1 = 5
|---------|---------|---------|
```

Al ordenar por `prioridad temporal` : 2, 4, **5**, 6, 8

```
-------------------------------
|prioridad|actividad|prioridad|
|original |         |temporal |
|---------|---------|---------|
|   1     |act1     |    2    |  <- prioridad original * 2
|   2     |act2     |    4    |
|   5     |act5     |    5    |  <- nueva prioridad * 2 - 1 
|   3     |act3     |    6    |
|   4     |act4     |    8    |
|---------|---------|---------|
```

Agregamos un contador para obtener un rango de prioridades entre 1 y 5:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|prioridad| actividad | prioridad | prioridad |
|original |           | temporal  | nueva     |
|---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   1     |act1       |     2     |     1     |      
|   2     |act2       |     4     |     2     |
|   5     |act5       |     5     |     3     |
|   3     |act3       |     6     |     4     |
|   4     |act4       |     8     |     5     |
|---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

---

Escrito en `SQL`:

```
SET @actividad = 'act5';
SET @prioridad = 3;

SELECT
  prioridad AS prioridadoriginal,
  actividad,
  CASE
    WHEN (actividad = @actividad)
       THEN IF (
       prioridad >= @prioridad,
       @prioridad * 2 - 1,
       @prioridad * 2 + 1 )
    ELSE (prioridad * 2)
  END AS prioridadtemporal,
  @rank:=@rank+1 AS prioridadnueva
FROM ACT_Agenda
ORDER BY prioridadtemporal ASC
```

verlo funcionando:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ae2bb/1/3

---

### B. el UPDATE

Para realizar el `UPDATE` basado en un `SELECT` hay que hacer un `JOIN` , algo asi:

```
SET @actividad = 'act5';
SET @prioridad = 3;

SET @rank=0;
UPDATE ACT_Agenda A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    actividad, 
    CASE 
    WHEN (actividad = @actividad)
      THEN IF (
        prioridad >= @prioridad,
        @prioridad * 2 - 1,
        @prioridad * 2 + 1 )
      ELSE (prioridad * 2)
    END AS prioridadtemporal,
    @rank:=@rank+1 AS prioridadnueva
  FROM ACT_Agenda
  ORDER BY prioridadtemporal ASC
  ) AS T on T.actividad = A.actividad
SET A.prioridad = T.prioridadnueva
```

verlo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe344c/1/0

### C. el PHP

Para lograr que el índice (`@rank`) empiece en `0` hay que hacer dos consultas: el `SET` y el `UPDATE`, meter todo en una sola query no funciona salvo que se use [`multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) pero ahí no podemos bindear los parámetros como sentencia preparada. Quedaría algo así:

```
$actividad = "act5"; $prioridad = intval(3);

// Multiple queries
$query1 = "SET @rank=0";
$query2 = "
UPDATE ACT_Agenda A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    prioridad AS prioridadoriginal,
    actividad,
    CASE
      WHEN (actividad = ?)
       THEN IF ( prioridad >= ?, ? * 2 - 1, ? * 2 + 1 )
      ELSE (prioridad * 2)
    END AS prioridadtemporal,
    @rank:=@rank+1 AS prioridadnueva
  FROM ACT_Agenda
  ORDER BY prioridadtemporal ASC
  ) AS T on T.actividad = A.actividad
SET A.prioridad = T.prioridadnueva
";
// Query 1 : SET @rank
$stmt1 = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt1->prepare($query1);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->store_result();
$stmt1->close();
// Query 2 : prepare & bind params
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare($query2)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("siii", $actividad, $prioridad, $prioridad, $prioridad);
  $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

**nota:** por limitaciones en la forma de hacer el binding hay que repetir `$prioridad` para rellenar todas las ocurrencias.